# What are the numbers near the registers mean in assembly?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

Hopefully this question is suitable for this forum. I'm very new to assembly. So, I'm trying to change some of the code of the game in cheat engine. Lets say for example we have something like this in the code:
mov [rsp+35],rax
Can someone please tell me what the number 35 mean?

Comment: If you are trying to learn assembly language, you should get a book or other reference. That reference will introduce you to the concepts, and along the way, it will explain what the 35 means. If you have difficulty understanding the book, you can ask a question about it here. But this site is not intended to teach you assembly language.

Comment: It's a byte offset from where the register points.  But if you didn't already know that, there's probably a lot more that you need to know, as Raymond says, so look for a tutorial or book.